# Jquery Cycle plugin - slideshow images move on mouseover IE8

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-cycle

I'm fairly new to jquery and I've encountered a very frustrating problem with the cycle plugin for jquery.

For some bizarre reason, in IE8 on Win-XP (seems to work ok on IE8 Win-7) if I move the mouse over the slideshow images, the whole slideshow jumps down about 80 pixels, then jumps back up to where it is meant to be when i move the mouse off it.

Here is the test site:
http://www.petsdomain.com.au/natures_test/index.html

The strange thing is it happens on Win8 IE-10 as well.  I'm fairly stumped by this.  As always, IE giving me grief!

Any helpers?

Comment: Please at least post the `mouseover` code so we don't have to go looking through your link for it. ^^

Comment: there is no mouseover code - its a jquery cycle slideshow plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting `position: absolute` on your `ul.nav` should fix your problem. You should set its width to `100%` as well.